# Dep confuses the projects in vendor to that in GOPATH

Tags: go, dependencies, dependency-management

I have projectA which imports packages from projectB.
Both are existing in the GOPATH.
I use dep for dependency management and projectB is added as a dependency in the Gopkg.toml of the projectA.

If I clear this projectB from the vendor directory of projectA or if I add it explicitly to the `ignored = ["projectB"]` It compiles fine.
Otherwise I get the kind of following errors:

```
"gitlab.internal.com/client/vendor/gitlab.internal.com/runtime/protocol/client".Connector does not implement "gitlab.internal.com/runtime/protocol/client".Connector (wrong type for ApplicationContext method)
        have ApplicationContext() *"gitlab.internal.com/client/vendor/gitlab.internal.com/runtime/core".ApplicationContext
        want ApplicationContext() *"gitlab.internal.com/runtime/core".ApplicationContext
```

The only difference from the 'have' and 'want' packages above is the path from where it is coming from. (One from GOPATH, the other from vendor/ of the projectA, which has this compilation issue)

I have the following questions:

1. Why is GOPATH being searched at all, given it is available in the
   vendor/? (Why does it state it 'wants' the dependency only from this place!?)
2. Is there a way to get the dep pick the dependency
   explicitly from vendor/?

Deleting the projectB from the GOPATH doesn't solve the problem either.
What is the issue here?

Comment: You should never have a package with a `vendor/` directory vendored in your project (or more loosely, you can't depend on a package with a `vendor/` directory -- i.e. "libraries" shouldn't vendor their dependencies). Whatever tools you are using should have a way to flatten the vendored dependencies into your top-level project. If you have the ability to change over now, go modules makes this much easier to do.